# Notation for function being differentiable at a certain point

Tags: calculus, notation, derivatives

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/84238/83069) describes a notation for a function $f(x)$ being (continuously) differentiable on some domain $A$.

Often, I see the requirement that some function $f(x)$ be differentiable only (or rather, at least) at a certain point $\tilde{x}$. This is usually written in plain text (e.g. "let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be differentiable at $\tilde{x}$").

I was wondering whether there is some more formal notation for such (local) differentiability. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just say 'where' your function is differentiable, because anyway differentiability is always a local concept. So let $f : X \to Y$ where $Y$ is some 'numerical' set (e.g. $\mathbb R^n$ or $\mathbb C^n$...) and let $A \subseteq X$ be the set of points where $f$ is differentiable. I think that's just fine. There's no need to be more precise unless you do something reaaaaally specific.

Hope that helps,

Comment: So would the notation $f \in C^1\!(\tilde{x})$ be correct then?

Comment: @Bernd : Well any notation is fine if it's not disturbing and it means what it looks like. Why do you want to find such a notation?

Comment: I'd want such notation because I keep repeatedly reading/writing "Suppose that the utility function is differentiable at $(\bar{x},\bar{y})$" and would find it a lot more convenient (and shorter) to replace it with $u\in C^1\!(\bar{x},\bar{y})$ - **if** this is correct notation.

Comment: @Bernd : My tip would be to just keep writing that, because users that will try to read you will understand you better than if you define some notation that they've never seen before, and you don't pay the price with a lot of words. (If you *would* pay the price with a lot of words, then a notation is relevant...) By the way, being differentiable and $C^1$ is not the same thing, even at a point ; distinguish the two.

Comment: So is the difference between $C^1$ and being differentiable that the former also implies continuity of the derivative? If so, I again wonder what would be a correct notation for local differentiability, although you are right about the possibility of confusing the reader (I am also asking this w.r.t. personal notes which should have proper notation nevertheless).

Comment: The reason why I'm reluctant to you trying to introduce such a notation is because for instance if we decide to choose "$C^1(x)$" as being continuously differentiable at one point, this is confusing with $C^1(A)$ which means the set of all functions $f : A \to Y$ where $f$ is actually $C^1$ in the common sense. What I mean is that anyway I can't think of any results which require to assume strictly speaking that a function is only $C^1$ at a point. We don't create notations for no reason ; we create them when they are relevant because a lot of results assume that.

Comment: The right question you can ask yourself is this : are there any relevant results you can think of that require that the function considered $f$ be differentiable at only one point? I can't think of any. The results I have in mind are for instance : Fermat's rule for extremas, change of variables formulas for integrals, implicit function and inverse function theorems, and so on. These results all require differentiability on the interior of the domain, some of them need $C^1$. That's why we have those notations.